Suppose $M$ is a connected manifold with nonempty boundary, then $D(M)$ is connected
Here's my proof.
Let $D(M)=M_1\cup_{\partial{M}}M_2$ where $M=M_1=M_2$
Assume $D(M)$ is disconnected, i.e., $D(M)=U\cup V$ disjoint union of open sets.
Since $M_1$ and $M_2$ are connected, then it must be that $M_1 \subseteq U$ and $M_2 \subseteq V$. Now consider $p \in \partial{M}$, since $\partial M \subset M_1 \text{ and } \partial M \subset M_2$, we get that $U\cap V \not= \emptyset$. Thus the union can't be disjoint. So $D(M)$ must be connected.
Is this reasonament correct? Thanks!

What does  $\cup_{\partial M}$ mean? If it means $M_1$ attached to $M_2$ via the identity on $\partial M_1=\partial M_2$, then your reasoning looks pretty good to me

You can simply quote a theorem (lemma) from general topology: If $X$ is a union of connected subsets with nonempty intersection, then $X$ is connected.

@Tom Yes, it means that attachment, as it is the adjuntion space of the manifold with itself

worth proving that $M \backslash \partial M$ is connected too.
